# Most effective way to 'listen' for data on a Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, web-services, rest, server

I am currently using a dedicated Mac Mini (OS X Yosemite) to handle mail-merges of Pages (a proprietary format) documents, that is triggered by an Applescript 'Mail-Rule' via incoming push iCloud mail.

However, relying on Mail is proving both inconsistent (will randomly miss some email) and high-latency (can take a long time for push to register even if it is supposed to be instant) — where speed is important.

What I want to achieve is a 'fast-as-possible' receipt of a small amount of data (think a 20-line JSON dictionary) on the Mac, which will then be used to trigger an Applescript action.

**Therefore, is there a commonly-accepted / best-practice way of 'listening' for requests that can be sent over the web like this, to OS X?** - i.e. similar to acting as a server implementing a RESTful API / a web-service.

I am literate in primarily front-end and native languages (Obj-C, Swift, JS) but am very open to learning new technologies if there is a neat and simple way of doing this.

My current train of thought is to create a native app that implements a library such as [RESTEasy](https://github.com/smyrgl/RESTEasy) that will listen and act accordingly — but I was curious if there is a better way of doing this.

And yes, I have to use OS X to get this done (relying on too many proprietary processes).

Comment: You can just run Apache and write some scripts in PHP or Perl to accept the requests. You can also just write a TCP server of your own with your own protocol. I would say the former is more common but not always the best way.

Comment: I had no idea that Apache 2.4 was *included* in OS X, let alone that you could even run it! The things you learn... I'll update my question when I sort it out, but in the meantime, thanks @johnelemans :)